# react-dateTime picker Css not working

Tags: reactjs, react-datetime

I am using [react-dateTime](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime) Picker. react-datetime picker's css is not working.can any one tell me why it look like.
It looks like this.
[image]

and second one this following function is working but css is working.

```
var yesterday = Datetime.moment().subtract( 1, 'day' );
var valid = function( current ){
    return current.isAfter( yesterday );
};
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share more of the component where you use the dateTime component? Specifically, how are you loading the CSS for the component?

Comment: I am not loading css. i just install react-dateTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Iggy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5739288/iggy)  add the following code in your webpack.config file.
 **'script-loader!react-datetime/dist/react-datetime.min.js',**

```
 entry: [
       'script-loader!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
       'script-loader!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js',
       'script-loader!react-datetime/dist/react-datetime.min.js',//add this line in your webpack.config file
      './app/app.jsx'],
      externals:{
        jquery:'jQuery'

      },
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to load the CSS file included with the react-dateTime picker. There's a small note in the docs regarding this but it's easy to miss.

You need to include [this CSS file](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime/blob/master/css/react-datetime.css) at some point. This could be copied into a master CSS file, or imported into the component where you use the react-dateTime picker.

```
import "path/to/node_modules/react-datetime/css/react-datetime.css";
```

Comment: Error: Cannot find module "/node_modules/react-datetime/css/react-datetime.css"

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more about your setup. You might have to play with the path to get it correct, or use a webpack loader for the CSS file.

Comment: I tried to copy all css and store in style folder with new file but this also not worked for me.

Comment: @Sweety, I am having similar issue. I copy+paste CSS but it does not change the appearance at all. I am 99% sure the problem is with my webpack. Do you mind sharing the configuration of your webpack to make CSS works?

Comment: @Iggy add the following code in your webpack.config file. 'script-loader!react-datetime/dist/react-datetime.min.js',

Comment: Haha, yeahhh... that CSS file makes a big difference. Thanks!