# Center align react-datetime inside modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-datetime

I'm building a modal that will allow user to select date and time. I'm using the [react-datetime component](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime).

Here is my code:

```
<div className="date-time-modal">
  <div className="date-time-modal-container">
    <div className="date-time-modal-button">
      <Button onClick={this.handleCloseModal} type="noborder">
        <Icon name="window-close" size={"2x"} />
      </Button>
    </div>
    <div className="date-time-modal-title">
      "Please select date and time:"
    </div>
    <div className="date-time-modal-calendar"> 
      <DateTime input={false} />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my styling:

```
.date-time-modal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 5%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: $ux-theme-color-modal-brackground;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-container: center;

}

.date-time-modal-container {
    background-color: $ux-theme-color-template-header;
    padding: 20px;

}

.date-time-modal-button {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
}

.date-time-modal-title {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: left;
}

.date-time-modal-calendar {
    flex: 1;
}

.date-time-modal-calendar * {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Every time the modal is opened the calendar is locked to the left side. If I choose the time picker, it became stacked.

Below current render (check the time picker stacked and all left aligned):

[image]

[image]

I need the picker to be centered on the parent  as well as the hous picker to behave normally (hour and minutes aside).

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199630/react-datetime-picker-css-not-working)

The component must be styled properly using react-datetime css files.